# Regarding mongodb deployment as container in AWS Fargate

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I want to deploy Mongo image on a container service like amazon Fargate.
can i write data to that container, if its possible to write data to the container where the data will be stored and they will charge it as a task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Fargate task (PV 1.4) comes with 20GB of ***ephemeral*** storage included in the price. You can extend it up to 200GB (for an additional fee). See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/fargate-task-storage.html). Again this space is ***ephemeral***, if the task shuts down your disk is wiped.

One other option (in this case ***persistent***) would be to [mount an EFS volume to the Fargate task](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/developers-guide-to-using-amazon-efs-with-amazon-ecs-and-aws-fargate-part-1/) but probably not a great fit for a database workload.